Unity new input system generate C# class without action map
I create an input actions which has an action map named Player.

I use it to generate a C# class named PlayerControls.
I new PlayerControls in the other script, but it does not include the definition of Player
Why the script does not include the action map?
How can I fix it?
public class InputManager : MonoBehavior
{
    private PlayerInputActions _inputActions;

    private void Awake
    {
        _inputActions = new PlayerInputActions();
        _inputActions.Player... //Player mark with red line
    }

}


Please, try to not post code via images as stated in [ask]. Also, do you want to retrieve the user of your PlayerInput? Maybe this can help

@CcmU I think in the case of highlighting how the IDE fails to resolve something a picture is actually fine. A combination of both would still be optimal I agree. In this case OP tries to access the Player action map that was added to the Input actions asset (see first image most left)

The little (*) next to the name of the Input Actions Asset indicates unsaved changes.
Should probably be resolved by hitting the Save Asset button. This will trigger the regeneration of the
according c# class.
Alternatively you could consider to enable the [] Auto Save toggle so it will automatically happen after each change.
